# How to avoid Sharp edge/angle when join end point with start point in path for Custom Painter Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bezier

[image: Attached image is current output, Issue: Left top, sharp edge/angle can be seen.]Getting issue to remove sharp edge/angle while connecting last point with first one while drawing shape using Custom Painter.

I am trying to create custom shape using CustomPainter. I have created Path using some points. And for drawing path, I am using Bezier. My Code is as per below. But when last point connects to first one, it creates sharp angle. How I can avoid it?

```
// preparing path points for shape.
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
  borderPoints.add(BorderPoint(xPoint, yPoint, radian, randomRadius, MovementDirection.INWARD));
}
borderPoints.add(borderPoints[0]);

// here, we are creating path for our shape.
jellyPath.moveTo(borderPoints[0].dx, borderPoints[0].dy);
int i = 1;

for (i = 1; i < borderPoints.length - 2; i++) {
  var xc = (borderPoints[i].dx + borderPoints[i + 1].dx) / 2;
  var yc = (borderPoints[i].dy + borderPoints[i + 1].dy) / 2;
  jellyPath.quadraticBezierTo(
      borderPoints[i].dx, borderPoints[i].dy, xc, yc);
}
jellyPath.quadraticBezierTo(borderPoints[i].dx, borderPoints[i].dy, borderPoints[i + 1].dx, borderPoints[i + 1].dy);
```

Expecting smooth curve while joining end part in Path.

Comment: post two images: with what you expect and what you got

Comment: @pskink I have updated my question and added image which is current output.

Comment: @pskink, thank you very much, it working as expected.

Comment: sure, your welcome - it you want you can remove `controlPaint` and any drawing operations with it as it was used for testing only

Comment: @pskink yes, I removed controlPaints as you suggested. If possible. please share the answer(right now, it's in comment), so if any one else comes with the samething, can easily understand the solution. Once again thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195893/discussion-between-jigar-and-pskink).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this simple drawing code (you have to modify it to work with your `BorderPoint` - whatever it is):

```
var p = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..color = Colors.deepPurple
  ..strokeWidth = 2;

var points = [
  Offset(100, 100),
  Offset(200, 150),
  Offset(250, 300),
  Offset(150, 350),
  Offset(150, 250),
  Offset(50, 200),
];

// you can remove "controlPaint" - it is for testing only
var controlPaint = Paint()..color = Color(0x880000ff);
var path = Path();
var mid = (points[0] + points[1]) / 2;
path.moveTo(mid.dx, mid.dy);
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var p1 = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
  var p2 = points[(i + 2) % points.length];
  mid = (p1 + p2) / 2;
  path.quadraticBezierTo(p1.dx, p1.dy, mid.dx, mid.dy);

  // draw control points and lines: switch it on by pressing 'p' key
  // when executing "flutter run" command
  // note it is for testing purposes only
  if (debugPaintSizeEnabled)
    canvas
      ..drawCircle(mid, 3, controlPaint)
      ..drawCircle(points[i], 5, controlPaint)
      ..drawLine(points[i], p1, controlPaint);
}
canvas.drawPath(path, p);
```

Comment: What kind of variable is "mid" that by assigning one value returns "mid.dx, mid.dy"?

Comment: @BrainCrash `Offset + Offset` gives `Offset` and `Offset` / `double` gives `Offset` too